# making a JavaScript character selector

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make a character selector, which select each character separately every time button pressing. But its not working at all

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <br />
      <p id="temp">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
      <br />
      <input type="button" onclick="selector()" value="SELECT" />

      <script>

        var x = document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML;
        var i = 0;

        function selector() {
          x.charAt(i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
          i++;
        }

      </script>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't style a single character. I would suggest wrapping all individual characters each in a `span`, and styling that.

Comment: Challenge becomes, @evolutionxbox, to make sure you're not wrapping each character of any nested tags. Given the innerHTML shown, that's not an issue. But if this same code gets reused with descendant tags, you would be thoroughly breaking them by this approach.

Comment: @Armin The `selector()` function does increment `i`.

Comment: Thanks so much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation

- Create a list of characters in the HTML element by using `string#split`.
- Wrap each of these characters inside a span tag. This is easy to do using the `map` function. We want to check if these are alphabetical characters so we use the `test` function.
- We then need to find the number of characters in the original string. We can do that by stripping the new string of all of it's span tags. Set the initial index to the first character, which in JavaScript is zero.
- Call an event listener. This could be for example `keydown`, which listens for keypresses.
- All of our characters have now been wrapped with a char class. To find a particular one, use `document.querySelectorAll`, and pass in `[index]`
- In the event that we cycle through the string, we will remove the styling for the last character in the list. Otherwise, naturally, the previous character will be converted back to normal.

```js
var chars = document.getElementById("par").innerHTML.split('');

var wrapped = chars.map( c =>  /[a-z]/i.test(c) ? "<span class='char'>" + c + "</span>" : "").join('');
var numLetters = wrapped.replace(/<span class='char'>/g, '').replace(/<\/span>/g, '').length;

document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = wrapped;

var index = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".char")[index].style.color = "red";
    if (index == 0) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".char")[numLetters - 1].style.color = "black";
    }
    if (index > 0) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".char")[index - 1].style.color = "black";
    }
    index = index == numLetters - 1 ? 0 : index + 1
});
```

```html
<p id="par">This is a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much ;):)

Comment: Happy I could help

Answer (score 5):

The primary issue is that you can only apply styling to HTML elements, not individual characters that make up the text content of an element.

This is why you are getting the "undefined" error that you are... `backgroundColor` can't be set on `undefined`, which refers to the return value of the `style` property, which doesn't exist on individual characters.

So first, you must wrap the character(s) to be highlighted in another element (a `<span>` is the best choice here) and then you can have the contents of the `<span>` be highlighted.

You weren't exactly clear on whether each click of the button should highlight only the next character or if the highlighting should be extended to include the next character, so I have solutions for both of those below. See comments inline for detailed explanations:

**Solution #1 (highlight single character at a time)**

```js
// Get DOM reference to paragraph (not contents of paragraph)
var x = document.getElementById("temp");

// Get DOM reference to button so we can wire it up to 
// an event handler in JS (not via inline event handling attributes).
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Set up event handler:
btn.addEventListener("click", selector);

var i = 0;

function selector() {
  
  // Get the character to be highlighted
  var char = x.textContent.charAt(i);
  
  // Set the contents of the paragraph to a new string that has the particular character
  // wrapped with a <span> that is set to use a predetermined class that does the actual
  // highlighting.
  x.innerHTML = x.textContent.replace(char, "<span class='highlight'>" + char + "</span>");
  
  // Increment i until we've hit the 26th value, then reset to 0
  i < 25 ? i++ : i = 0;
}
```

```css
.highlight { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<p id="temp">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
<br>

<!-- There is no closing tag for input elements! -->
<input type="button" id="btn" value="SELECT">
```

**Solution #2 (extend highlighting to include next character)**

```js
// Get DOM reference to paragraph (not contents of paragraph)
var x = document.getElementById("temp");

// Get DOM reference to button so we can wire it up to an event handler in JS (not via inline event 
// handling attributes).
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Set up event handler:
btn.addEventListener("click", selector);

var i = 0;

function selector() {
  
  // Get the character to be highlighted
  var char = x.textContent.charAt(i);
  
  // Set the contents of the paragraph to a new string that encloses all the characters
  // up to and including the current one in  a <span> that is set to use a predetermined 
  // class that does the actual highlighting.
  x.innerHTML = "<span class='highlight'>" + x.textContent.replace(char, char + "</span>");
  
  // Increment i until we've hit the 26th value, then reset to 0
  i < 25 ? i++ : i = 0;
}
```

```css
.highlight { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<p id="temp">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
<br>

<!-- There is no closing tag for input elements! -->
<input type="button" id="btn" value="SELECT">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all character into a span tag, and change the span background color.

```js
var i = 0;

function selector() {
  if (document.getElementById("temp_" + i)) 
    document.getElementById("temp_" + i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  i++;
}
```

```html
<p id="temp">
  <span id='temp_0'>A</span>
  <span id='temp_1'>B</span>
  <span id='temp_2'>C</span>
  <span id='temp_3'>D</span>
</p>

<button onclick='selector();'>Test</button>
```

Comment: My issue with this approach is that it forces a programmatic change on the cosmetic HTML. Those tags aren't required for the actual rendering of the page -- if you get it from a designer, they won't be there. So, in Scott Marcus' approach, he works with the HTML as is and makes any programmatic changes needed.

Comment: This is an reply to the question, to explain how to do. Scott  create span tag like me. But he created the span with JS. It's an other way. I am not here to post the best approach but explain how to resolved an issue.

Comment: Thanks so much ;) :)